# Pyodbc error Data source name not found and no default driver specified paradox

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am attempting to use `pyobdc` to read data from a paradox database, and I keep getting the following error when attempting to connect to the database:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have tried to create new DNS links for the database but it has not helped what so ever.

**My system links are as follows:**

[image: This is what the system DNS looks like]

**My code is:**

```
import os
import sys
import time
import pyodbc

LOCATION = "c:\Users\Marcello\Desktop\DATA\ScorMonitor.db"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={{Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )}};Fil=Paradox 5.X;DefaultDir={0};Dbq={0}; CollatingSequence=ASCII;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select last, first from test")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row
```

Comment: I don't know if you have seen this already but this post has a connection string for the paradox driver. Maybe you can try this to see if it helps resolve? It looks similar to yours, but some differences exist.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651087/is-it-possible-to-use-pyodbc-to-read-paradox-tables-that-are-open-in-the-paradox

Comment: Yes I followed all the steps that were suggested on that post and it did not solve the problem

Comment: Does your machine have the Borland Database Engine (or more modern compatible equivalent) installed?

Comment: @GordThompson no I do not

Comment: @GordThompson I do have the BDE Administrator

Comment: Assuming that your code is actually complete (the example is missing the format of the connection string to include LOCATION), try using double backslash on the path. I had this issue in windows systems, although I was using C# not python.

Comment: @rll the code posted above is my full code

Comment: then you should have:  "Driver={{Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )}};Fil=Paradox 5.X;DefaultDir={0};Dbq={0}; CollatingSequence=ASCII;".format(LOCATION)   Otherwise your {0} is not replaced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYODBC--Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Two thoughts on what to check:

1) Your connection string is wrong. There's a way to get a known good connection string directly from the ODBC Administrator program (taken from http://www.visokio.com/kb/db/dsn-less-odbc). These instructions assume you're using an MDB, but the same process will work for a paradox file

- On a typical client PC, open Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources.
- Select the File DSN  tab and click Add.
- Select the appropriate driver (e.g. "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)") and click Next
- Click Browse and choose where you want to save the .dsn file (this is a temporary file you are going to delete later).
- Click Next then Finish.
- You will be shown the vendor-specific ODBC setup dialog. For example, with Microsoft Access, you might only need to click Select and browse to an existing .mdb file before clicking OK.
- Browse to the location of the .dsn file and open using Notepad.

In the DSN file you might see something similar to:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
UID=admin
UserCommitSync=Yes
Threads=3
SafeTransactions=0
PageTimeout=5
MaxScanRows=8
MaxBufferSize=2048
FIL=MS Access
DriverId=25
DefaultDir=C:\
DBQ=C:\db1.mdb
```

To convert the above to the full connection strring:

1. Omit the first [ODBC] line
2. Put curly braces around all values containing spaces
3. Put all name=value pairs on one line, separated by semicolons.

This gives you the full connection string. In this example, the string becomes:

```
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;axScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\;DBQ=C:\db1.mdb
```

2) 32/64 bit mismatch. I've had troubles when mixing 32-bit python with 64-bit drivers, or vice-versa. You may want to check your Python interpreter and database driver line up.

Comment: Thank you for such a through answer. But I was wondering where I can find the DNS like that. I am very new to having to use a driver to access as database.

Comment: You don't have to find the DSN file. The process I described will generate a DSN file. From there you can get the full connection string, as described. The only thing you'll need to do is pick the right driver and select the right file, both of which it seems you already know.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense now. Applying what I have learned from your post gives me this error: `KeyError: 'Microsoft Paradox Driver (*'` I am terribly sorry but this is a very new area for me.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you remember to add the curly braces? Like this: DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)} If it's not that, you may want to start a new question, giving the full connection string in the question, as well as whatever code before and after is necessary for context.

Comment: Will you take a quick look before I post a new question? http://pastebin.com/Y6HDwvda

Comment: Ah, I see. You should remove the .format(LOCATION) part. That will fix your error. However, I notice you had set LOCATION to a different file from what you have listed under the DBQ tag in the connection string. Make sure you know which file contains the database you care about.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Once I ran it a second time it broke with the same error code

Comment: Thanks. The 32/64-bit mismatch was my issue.

Comment: So, I was trying this today. In my case, it was failing to connect when I had curly braces around DefaultDir and DBQ even though the file path had spaces in in. I also had to replace \ with \\. With curly braces gone and \\ in filepath, it worked fine even with spaces in filepath.

Answer (score 13):

You need a Microsoft Office version compatible with your Python installation, i.e. both of them must be either 32 bit or 64 bit.
From the [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access) documentation:

> There are actually two (2) different Access ODBC drivers from Microsoft:
>
> 1. `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` - This is the older 32-bit "Jet" ODBC driver. It is included as a standard part of a Windows install. It only works with `.mdb` (not `.accdb`) files. It is also officially deprecated.
> 2. `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` - This is the newer "ACE" ODBC driver. It is not included with Windows, but it is normally included as part of a Microsoft Office install. It is also available as a free stand-alone "redistributable" [installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for machines without Microsoft Office. There are separate 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the "ACE" Access Database Engine (and drivers), and normally one has **either** the 64-bit version **or** the 32-bit version installed. (It is possible to force both versions to exist on the same machine but it is not recommended as it can "break" Office installations. Therefore, if you already have Microsoft Office it is *highly recommended* that you use a Python environment that matches the "bitness" of the Office install.)
>
> The easiest way to check if one of the Microsoft Access ODBC drivers is available to your Python environment (on Windows) is to do
>
> ```py
> >>> import pyodbc
> >>> [x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]
> ```
>
> If you see an empty list then you are running 64-bit Python and you need to install the 64-bit version of the "ACE" driver. If you only see `['Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)']` and you need to work with an `.accdb` file then you need to install the 32-bit version of the "ACE" driver.

Comment: The question was about reading a Paradox file, not an MS Access database. But thank you for your advice, because it helped me out.

Comment: simply listing all of pyodbc.drivers() hinted me to use driver version 17 instead of 13

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Helped me to find the underlying reason for the "Data Source Name not found"-error.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the question, I had a similar problem, and this question and the answers helped lead me to what I needed.
The problem for me ended up being a mismatch between 64-bit Python and 32-bit ODBC Driver on Windows 10 (as Chad Kennedy suggested).  I'm running a fully updated Fall Creator's Edition, and had Microsoft Office Pro 2016 installed.  The MS Office installer still defaults to a 32-bit installation (don't get me started...) -- it doesn't ask about this at install time, so imagine my surprise when I discovered I was running 32-bit Office.  Because of this, it installs the 32-bit ODBC driver for MS Access. There is a tiny unnoticeable link you can click in the MS Office installer dialog to force the 64-bit install.

A 64-bit Python installation won't work with the 32-bit Microsoft Access ODBC  driver, and Microsoft won't let you install the 64-bit ODBC driver if you have 32-bit MS Office installed on the machine.

The fix was to UNINSTALL MS Office, and re-install it by using that tiny link on the install dialog to tell it to install as 64-bit.  Don't worry, it remembers all of your recent files and settings, and email accounts in Outlook.  Once that was done, I had the 64-bit ODBC driver, and my Python code connected to the database with no further problems.

Comment: Even I had all in 64 bits but it does not work, I have to change all to 32 bits to make it work

Answer (score -1):

The shortcut for setting ODBC data sources maybe pointing to the 32bit data sources instead of 64bit.

Go to control panel -> administrative tools --> select data sources(ODBC) --> then right click on that file --> go to properties --> in the shortcut tab -> change the path from `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe` to

`%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`