# python connection to sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

**pyodbc.InterfaceError**:

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name
>   not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Probably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYODBC--Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see if the driver you're trying to use is visible from your Python app.

Comment: @gagan were you able to solve this?

Comment: Probably this link can solve your issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified/57819021#57819021

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
import pytds 

SERVER.IP = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
SERVER.DB_NAME = 'xxxxxx'
SERVER.USERNAME = 'xxxx'
SERVER.PWD = 'xxxxxx'

   with pytds.connect(SERVER.IP, SERVER.DB_NAME, SERVER.USERNAME, SERVER.PWD) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if conn == False:
            print("Error, Could not connect to the database")
        else:
            print("Connected to DB")
```