# How to connect my Sybase Database using SQLAlchemy (1.3.18) with Python (3.8.3)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sybase, pyodbc, sap-ase

I'm using SQL Server with SQLAlchemy 1.3.18 library and thanks to fast_executemany = True, it's now faster than before.

I have to make the link with a Sybase Database. I've got the following error:

> TypeError :  Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine(),using configuration SybaseDialect_pyodbc/QueuePool/Engine.

This is going to be a problem for me because I want a quick connection and also quick writing on my db.But even if I erase these arguments from the method, I've got the following error :

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationnalError : (pyodbc.OperationnalError)

here is the code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con['sql']['connexion_string'])
```

with `con['sql']['connexion_string'] = "sybase+pyodbc://<user>:<password>@server_name/[db_name]driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"`

I think it comes from the driver (maybe I'm wrong), but I don't know which one take, and in the documentation, I've understood we have to use pyodbc so ODBC Drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many search, i've found something where it's workin for me.

yo have to writre like an odbc connexion:

```py
    params = (
          "DRIVER = "+driver+";"\
          "SERVER = "+server+";"\
          "DATABASE = "+database+";"\
          "PORT = "+port+";"\
          "UID = "+user+";"\
          "PWD= "+password+";"

    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
```

where params is your odbc connexion.

And then do this :

```
connexion_string = 'sybase+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect = %s'%params)
```

with this connexion string, you're able to do sqlalchemy.create_engine(connexion_string)

Comment: can you share the driver paparameter ?

Answer (score 1):

The internal sybase dialect does not support fast_executemany, but the [external dialect](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase) does.

Note that you will need to use SAP's ODBC driver for ASE; FreeTDS ODBC won't work with fast_executemany.

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future, this is how i fixed my problem on Windows:

get ODBC dsn path: start>control_panel>admin_tools>ODBC_Data_source(64-bit)>
2 options here: check the system DSN tab. you might see something named like 'prototype' with SQL Anywhere 17 Driver.
or youll have to create your own DSN under `File Dsn` > Add > {select your dialect} > {Browse to save file path} > then click `Finish`. youll be prompted to fill in your Sql Anywhere info.... database name, Uid, PWD, etc...
check out Chad Kenneedy's answer to setup custom ODBC [Pyodbc error Data source name not found and no default driver specified paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox)

- make sure to test Dsn connection when you got it all figured out.

once thats done,

`engine = create_engine("sybase+pyodbc://<DSN_username>:<DSN_password>@<DSN_file_name,eg_prototype>")`