# Operational Error connecting to SQL Server through Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I am using Python 3.7 and for a few years I have had a Python script that connected to an SQL server with the below code:

```
con_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+ server +';DATABASE=' + database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Recently when running the script I get the below error:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1)')
```

I am not quite sure how to interpret this and have tried looking for solutions but had trouble understanding much of it?

Thanks

**Update 18 August 2020**

With Gords help I have updated my drivers and built a new connection string based on the answer below:

[Pyodbc error Data source name not found and no default driver specified paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox)

```
con_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};TrustServerCertificate=No;Network=DBMSSOCN;DATABASE='+database+';WSID=L13-CHRISTOPHER;APP={Microsoft® Windows® Operating System};Trusted_Connection=Yes;SERVER='+server+';'
```

But I am still getting the error

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1)')
```

Thanks

Comment: The "SQL Server" driver is very old. Try using a more modern driver like "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

Comment: Thanks Gord, I replaced "SQL Server" with "ODBC Driver 17" and got a new error message 
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: You need to install a driver before you can use it. Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are currently available to your Python app.

Comment: Thanks again Gord. I have updated the driver and it still wasn't working. So I found the below link and used the method to rebuild my connection string:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox  But the new connection string which worked on the test when buildin it is giving me the operational error again

Comment: New connection string in an edit in original question.

Answer (score 1):

**Method-1**:- Check this out:

`con_string = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server, database=db1, trusted_connection=tcon)`
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

If Method-1 doesn't work for you then maybe your SQL Server drivers require **TLS** 1.0 which would be disabled on your computer. Changing to the newest version of **SNAC** will fix the problem for you

`con_string = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',  host=server, database=db1, trusted_connection=tcon)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ansh, What is tcon? I can't find where it was defined.

Comment: A Trusted connection means Windows Authentication.

SQL Server has two Authentication modes: Mixed and Windows Authentication Mode.

Comment: You can omit it as well as it is optional.

Comment: If it works for you then do upvote the answer. Thanks !!